# Load Text file in react native locally

Tags: react-native

I am creating an application using **react native expo cli**, my application contains a lot of data which is in the text file.

So now i need to load the text file into my application. how can i do that?

Comment: A simplest method is create a json file to contain the content of those text file, then import the json file like :
import data from 'data.json';

Comment: Thank you @JamesLiu . I already have json file which is called data.json which contain array of object and object contain three properties which is ID,title and path. Now path contain a text file path which have lots of text. I am creating an application of Poem and Stories for kids and now i want to take render whole story from text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After dig down a lot regarding this issue i manage to answer my own question.
To read text file in react-native we have to create **bare** react-native project.

Read this link about manage and bare project for react-native : [expo-managed-vs-bare](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/managed-vs-bare/).

After eject expo project or creating bare react-native project you can use library [react-native-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs/v/1.2.0), which have ability to read text file and display in Text component.

**For Android**,

1. Create an assets Folder inside `your-project-file\android\app\src\main`
2. To read this folder assets use this snippet,

   import * as RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

   RNFS.readFileAssets(`path to your file inside assets folder`).then(result => {
         console.log(result);
       }).catch(err => {
         console.log(err);
       });

This will help to read text file inside your project for android only.

Answer (score 2):

As @james Liu,the simplest way is to organize your data as json an load it like this:

```
const data = require("./mydata.json");
```

By doing this you get an JS object you can easily handle in your code

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to load custom static assets also with expo, it's a bit convoluted though

1. First you need to tell the bundler (Metro) to bundle the files of interest, create a `metro.config.js` file in your root with this:

```js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('@expo/metro-config');

const configs = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
configs.resolver.assetExts.push('txt')

module.exports = configs;
```

you probably need to `npm i @expo/metro-config` as well.

2. Now using [Expo Asset](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/asset/) (`npx expo install expo-asset`) you have to download the file of interest from the bundle to the file system, so you can get access to it:

```js
import { Asset } from "expo-asset";

const { localUri } = await Asset.fromModule(require('/src/data/your-text-file.txt')).downloadAsync();
```

3. And using [Expo FileSystem](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/) (`npx expo install expo-file-system`) you can load your file content and parse it

```js
import { readAsStringAsync } from "expo-file-system";


const textContent = await readAsStringAsync(localUri);
console.log("My textfile: ", textContent);
```

Comment: The answer I was looking for. Thanks!